# ZPL Command to skip printing the first few characters in a text string

Tags: zpl

Does anyone know of a way to either not print say the first six characters of a data string that is passed or to wrap a long text string after the first 6 characters onto only one additional line?

Answer (score 1):

ZPL wont be able to skip characters. That would need to happen in a process before you create the ZPL or merge data with ZPL.

But, for your second question about wrapping text use the ^FB – Field Block command.  It is in the [ZPL Manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf).